# Key frame animation is jerky in ipad both safari and chrome. How to smooth animation in safari?

Tags: css, safari, css-transitions, css-animations, keyframe

I have done a ball animation rotation in 360 degree on button click at the same time it moves left and right. It works in chrome and opera perfectly but issues in firefox and iPad devices. In iPad devices animation is so much jerky so how to add smooth animation? In firefox, the number is not showing

```js
$(function(){
  $('#genBall').on("click", function () {
   $('.eight-ball').addClass("rotate-ball");
    setTimeout(RemoveClass, 2000);
   });
   function RemoveClass() {
    $('.eight-ball').removeClass("rotate-ball");
   }
  });
```

```css
.eight-ball {
    width: 475px;
    height: 475px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #1f84d0;
 transform: rotate(12deg);
 user-select: none;
 display: table;
}

.eight-ball:before {
 content: "";
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 background: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 top: 30px;
 left: 40px;
 z-index: 999;
 opacity: 0.8;
 border-radius: 50%;
 filter: blur(13px);
}

.eight-ball:after {
 content: "";
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 opacity: 0.7;
 position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
 border-radius: 50%;
 transform: rotate(-137deg);
 box-shadow: inset -3px 0 6px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 
    inset 50px 0 70px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.eight-ball-inner-white {
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 55px;
 margin-left: 6px;
    border-radius: 50%;
 position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgb(224,235,245);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(224,235,245,1) 0%, rgba(190,205,214,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(224,235,245,1) 0%,rgba(190,205,214,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(224,235,245,1) 0%,rgba(190,205,214,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e0ebf5', endColorstr='#becdd6',GradientType=0 );
}

.rotate-ball {
 -webkit-animation: rotateanim ease-in-out 2s;
    -moz-animation: rotateanim ease-in-out 2s;
    -ms-animation: rotateanim ease-in-out 2s;
    -o-animation: rotateanim ease-in-out 2s;
    animation: rotateanim ease-in-out 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateanim {
 0% {margin-left: 0px; transform: rotate(12deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(12deg); -moz-transform: rotate(12deg); -o-transform: rotate(12deg); -ms-transform: rotate(12deg);}
 30% {margin-left: 340px; transform: rotate(205deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(205deg); -moz-transform: rotate(205deg); -o-transform: rotate(205deg); -ms-transform: rotate(205deg);}
 50% {margin-left: -340px; transform: rotate(-320deg); transform: rotate(-320deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(-320deg); -moz-transform: rotate(-320deg); -o-transform: rotate(-320deg); -ms-transform: rotate(-320deg);}
 100% {margin-left: 0px; transform: rotate(12deg); transform: rotate(12deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(12deg); -moz-transform: rotate(12deg); -o-transform: rotate(12deg); -ms-transform: rotate(12deg);}
}

@keyframes rotateanim {
 0% {margin-left: 0px; transform: rotate(12deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(12deg); -moz-transform: rotate(12deg); -o-transform: rotate(12deg); -ms-transform: rotate(12deg);}
 30% {margin-left: 340px; transform: rotate(205deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(205deg); -moz-transform: rotate(205deg); -o-transform: rotate(205deg); -ms-transform: rotate(205deg);}
 50% {margin-left: -340px; transform: rotate(-320deg); transform: rotate(-320deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(-320deg); -moz-transform: rotate(-320deg); -o-transform: rotate(-320deg); -ms-transform: rotate(-320deg);}
 100% {margin-left: 0px; transform: rotate(12deg); transform: rotate(12deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(12deg); -moz-transform: rotate(12deg); -o-transform: rotate(12deg); -ms-transform: rotate(12deg);}
}

.eight-ball-inner-white span {
    color: #222b32;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 140px;
    font-weight: bold;
 transition: all ease 1s;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="eight-ball">
    <div class="eight-ball-inner-white spin-ball">
        <span>GO</span>
    </div>
</div>

<button id="genBall">play</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution. Added extra div after eightball class. Instead of giving rotation and movement to one div give separate animation to both div. Use movement to the main div and use rotation to child

```js
$(function(){
  $('#genBall').on("click", function () {
   $('.eight-ball').addClass("rotate-ball");
    setTimeout(RemoveClass, 2000);
   });
   function RemoveClass() {
    $('.eight-ball').removeClass("rotate-ball");
   }
  });
```

```css
.eight-ball {
  width: 475px;
  height: 475px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #1f84d0;
  user-select: none;
  display: table;
}

.eight-ball>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.eight-ball>div:before {
  content: "";
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 40px;
  z-index: 999;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-radius: 50%;
  filter: blur(13px);
}

.eight-ball:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-137deg);
  box-shadow: inset -3px 0 6px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), inset 50px 0 70px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.eight-ball-inner-white {
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 55px;
  margin-left: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(12deg);
  background: rgb(224, 235, 245);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(224, 235, 245, 1) 0%, rgba(190, 205, 214, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(224, 235, 245, 1) 0%, rgba(190, 205, 214, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(224, 235, 245, 1) 0%, rgba(190, 205, 214, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e0ebf5', endColorstr='#becdd6', GradientType=0);
}

.rotate-ball {
  -webkit-animation: rotateanim ease-in-out 2s;
  -moz-animation: rotateanim ease-in-out 2s;
  -ms-animation: rotateanim ease-in-out 2s;
  -o-animation: rotateanim ease-in-out 2s;
  animation: rotateanim ease-in-out 2s;
}

.rotate-ball>div {
  -webkit-animation: rotateanimInner ease-in-out 2s;
  -moz-animation: rotateanimInner ease-in-out 2s;
  -ms-animation: rotateanimInner ease-in-out 2s;
  -o-animation: rotateanimInner ease-in-out 2s;
  animation: rotateanimInner ease-in-out 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateanim {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(340px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(340px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: translate(340px, 0px);
    -o-transform: translate(340px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate(340px, 0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-340px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-340px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: translate(-340px, 0px);
    -o-transform: translate(-340px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate(-340px, 0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
}

@keyframes rotateanim {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(340px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(340px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: translate(340px, 0px);
    -o-transform: translate(340px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate(340px, 0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-340px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-340px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: translate(-340px, 0px);
    -o-transform: translate(-340px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate(-340px, 0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateanimInner {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(205deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(205deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(205deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(205deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(205deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-320deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-320deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-320deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-320deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-320deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotateanimInner {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(205deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(205deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(205deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(205deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(205deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-320deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-320deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-320deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-320deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-320deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

.eight-ball-inner-white span {
  color: #222b32;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 140px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all ease 1s;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="eight-ball">
  <div>
    <div class="eight-ball-inner-white spin-ball">
      <span id="bingoBalls">55</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<button id="genBall">play</button>
```